# Questioning the differentiability of $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} y- \frac{e^{x^2+y^2}-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2},& x^2+y^2 \neq 0. \\ -1, & x=y=0 \end{cases}$$

I keep runnung into trouble with these types of questions. The way I do them is the same as in this question: [Prove that the following functions is differentiable on $(-1,1) \times \mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409684/prove-that-the-following-functions-is-differentiable-on-1-1-times-mathbb-r/1409708#1409708)

But I run into trouble with the limits.. I was thinking polar coordinates, but am no sure how do put it together.

Comment: It's possible easier to prove that $$g(x,y)=\begin{cases}  \frac{e^{x^2+y^2}-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2},& x^2+y^2 \neq 0. \\ 1, & x=y=0 \end{cases}$$ is differentiable.  Then $f(x,y)=y-g(x,y)$. Then apply polar coordinates to $g(x,y)$ and use Taylor series to come up with Taylor series for $g$.

Comment: I believe there's an error in this question. Do you perhaps mean $e^{x^2+y^2} - 1$ in the numerator to get a finite limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, as is, $f(x,y)$ is not even continuous. @TedShifrin Somehow, I was reading it as $e^{x^2+y^2}-1$.

Comment: It would be easier turning the $-1$ into $0$ :P

Comment: $f$ is not even continuous at the origin.  And we are done.

Comment: @Dr.MV How are we done, before anything started? why is it not continuous?

Comment: It is discontinuous since the the limit of $g$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ diverges.  Check the numerator of the post.  The exponential term does not tend to 0.